# Ripple filter @ 2 amp without breaking the bank?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, ripple

I'm trying to create a +160v and +/- 100v supply that with idle at 2A.
The problem I'm having is I can't find capacitors that can handle the ripple currents for the prefilter. I need to order like $200 worth of caps to keep the ripple currents barely within spec.
LC and RC filters don't work because without a capacitor before them the DC loss is too great.
Is there a sane way to filter at these currents?
A few volts of ripple is fine, I just need the caps to not die after a month.
Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: What ripple currents are you expecting, and how did you determine them?

Comment: There are high-ripple capacitors for SMPS applications. In what way are these not good enough? Is ESR a factor as well?

Comment: For example, a 10,000uf capacitor filtering @ 2A DC will, according to LTSpice, have ripple currents of 29A @ 160v. A 10,000uf cap cannot handle that.

Comment: Could you post your LT Spice?

Comment: Posted it to opener.

Comment: To start with, you need to understand the difference between peak current (what the simulation is showing you) and RMS current, which is what the capacitor rating is based on. Zoom in on the current waveform so that you can see individual cycles to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Oh damn I didn't notice it said RMS. How do I calculate the RMS current? Multiply the peak by 0.7 right?

Comment: RMS of 30 would be 21. Still not a practical difference in cost of the capacitor.

Comment: Source resistance can have a marked effect on peak current. Assuming the AC voltages will be supplied by a transformer, what are its likely specs (eg. VA rating, winding resistances)? You said "A **few** volts of ripple is fine" - would 3-4 volts be OK?

Comment: 0.7 only applies for a sinusoidal current which this will not be. Also you may with to consider what your source impedance really is, it makes a huge difference to the conduction angle and hence to the RMS ripple. To calculate the RMS ripple integrate the square of the current over a cycle then take the square root.

Comment: My math literacy is a bit shaky, the answer to that for my given example should be 10 right?

Comment: (`didn't notice it said RMS` apropos: far as I remember, voltages in spice source specs are *peak*) A "choke input" filter will need more input voltage for the same output voltage, but don't call it "DC loss" - the loss in transformer+rectifier+filter should be *less* than with a capacitor input.